# Asp.net prevent HTML injection?

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, code-injection, html-injections

In asp.net how do i prevent html injection:

```
http://example.com?id=asd"%20href="http://google.com"><>
```

crome disallow but firefox allow to run that script. Is there any way to prevent HTML injection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Microsoft Tutorial about it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647397.aspx

and this one is about SQL Injection:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

[image]

^^ still from the ms tuts...

Comment: I saw that link. But there is no reference for **HTML injection**.

Comment: isn't there a way to solve it by using web.config. E.g: **validateRequest="true"**

Comment: Im not 100% sure but i think i have never seen a automatic option for it... i thinks there its only possible to do it with your own implementation... you could use a filter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters , that way would only to implement it once.

Comment: Thanks, i implemented that code in my global.asax file, if any querystring have invalid HTML paramater, then i will redirect it to 404.aspx.